# Java JSON: get object-value without quotes?

Tags: java, json, javax.json

I parse a JSON string.
How can I get the value of an object without the quotes? I get it with lists but it is not working with objects.

```
import javax.json.*;
import javax.json.stream.*;
```

...

```
    String s="{ \"foo\" : [ \"abc\", \"def\" ],   \"bar\" : { \"k1\" : \"v1\", \"k2\" : \"v2\" } }";

    JsonReader jr = Json.createReader(new StringReader (s));
    JsonObject jo = jr.readObject();

    JsonArray foo = jo.getJsonArray ("foo");
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.size (); i ++)
    {
        System.out.println (i + ": " + foo.getString (i));  // ok, no quotes
    }

    JsonObject bar = jo.getJsonObject ("bar");
    for (Map.Entry <String, JsonValue> e : bar.entrySet ())
    {
        System.out.println (e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue ().toString()); 
    }
```

Thats the output.

```
0: abc
1: def
k1: "v1"
k2: "v2"
```

How can I get v1 and v2 without quotes out of the parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know your input value are String, so you can do this:

```
for (Map.Entry <String, JsonValue> e : bar.entrySet ()) {
    System.out.println (e.getKey() + ": " + ((JsonString)e.getValue ()).getString()); 
}
```